# How to deserialize this JSON to C# Class

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

i'am working with a WebAPI that returns this json from a Request

```
{
    "apps": {
        "570": {
            "228983": {
                "8124929965194586177": "available"
            },
            "228990": {
                "1829726630299308803": "available"
            },
            "373301": {
                "840315559245085162": "available"
            },
            "373302": {
                "688854584180787739": "available"
            },
            "373303": {
                "3675525977143063913": "available"
            },
            "373305": {
                "4435851250675935801": "available"
            },
            "381451": {
                "6984541794104259526": "available"
            },
            "381452": {
                "1442783997179322635": "available"
            },
            "381453": {
                "6878143993063907778": "available"
            },
            "381454": {
                "7824447308675043012": "available"
            },
            "381455": {
                "5681120743357195246": "available"
            }
        },
        "674940": {
            "674941": {
                "6246860772952658709": "available"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It returns A list of AppID (int), that contains another list of DepotID, that it Contains a ManifestID (Key) and if it's aviable or not (Value).

And i want to deserialize to a class to easy work with it, but i can't imagine how to do it. I'am a newbie in C# comming from C/C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how much is gained by modeling this as C# classes without property names beyond the "apps" level of your Json, but you *could* do it like so:

Model your Json with the following classes:

```
public class AppIds : Dictionary<string, DepotId> { }
public class DepotId : Dictionary<string, ManifestId> { }
public class ManifestId : Dictionary<string, string> { }
```

And then you can do like so using Newtonsoft.Json

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string jsonPath = @"c:\debug\data.json";
        System.IO.Stream s = new System.IO.FileStream(jsonPath,System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);

        AppIds data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, AppIds>>(File.ReadAllText(jsonPath))["apps"];
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/) which is a popular JSON library for C#. See [Deserialize an Object](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm).

Example:

```
public class MyData
{
    public Dictionary<long, Dictionary<long, Dictionary<long, string>>> apps { get; set; }
}

var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>(json);

// Use 'data.apps'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Newtonsoft.Json NuGet package and deserialize your data to a nested dictionary like so:

`var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>>>(File.ReadAllText("Data.json"));`

To make sure you got the right data you can run this code to print it out:

`foreach (var a in data)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a.Key);
    foreach (var b in a.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + b.Key);
        foreach (var c in b.Value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t" + c.Key);
            foreach (var d in c.Value)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t" + d.Key + ": " + d.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}`

Not really sure how to deserialize this data to a class since it doesn't have much in the way of property names...

Comment: Without property names beyond "apps" I think all you can really do is dump it in to a nested dictionary. OP could create a class to represent the hierarchy, e.g., something like `ManifestID` inheriting `Dictionary<string,string>`, a class for `DepotId: Dictionary<string, ManifestId>` and a class for `AppId: Dictionary<string, DepotId>` but I'm not sure what's really gained by that.